# How i can block any kind of video on my router?

Tags: router, video, blocking

How can I block every  kind of video on  my router ?
I already block you tube on my Router by filter the domain names 
but my staff use mobile applications like `musicaly.ly` etc.

Now I want to block all kind of video?

Comment: One could say the correct answer to this is to get a router that is capable of this type restriction, one that comes to mind is Meraki with advanced content filtering... Or lock down everything except what you want, for example deny all traffic except the basic essentials like http/https, smtp, etc. Then again, if the video is being delivered as an https stream, none of this will work anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately a router has limited vision when it comes to applications or filetypes that a client device is accessing. In other words, it is difficult for a router to identify a video vs other data. If you are concerned about them viewing videos at work, it probably is best to address that personally and not technologically (people always find a way). If you are concerned about bandwidth - you can apply aggressive QoS that severely throttles a connection after it uses a certain amount of data.